# Add files to a zip and download MVC5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know why returning a zip file, then opening the files contained in it, can not open, and tells me that the files are corrupted, someone understands the following method and detects something wrong?
Many thanks to who can contribute, that is the method in my controller:

```
 Public FileResult Download ()
        {
            List <String> codes = new List <string> ();
            Codes.Add ("1079");
            Codes.Add ("1078");
            Codes.Add ("1077");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream (); ;
            Using (var zip = new ZipArchive (ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                Foreach (string codigoGar in codes)
                {
                    String mimetypeOfFile = "";
                    Guarantees oGarantia = ControllerGarantias.getGarantia (SessionHelper.GetEntorno (), codeGar);
                    Var stream = new MemoryStream (oGarantia.comprobante);


                    Byte [] buffer = new byte [1024];
                    If (stream.Length> = 1024)
                        Stream.Read (buffer, 0, 1024);
                    Else
                        Stream.Read (buffer, 0, (int) stream.Length);

                    Try
                    {
                        System.UInt32 mimetype;
                        FindMimeFromData (0, null, buffer, 1024, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
                        System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr (mimetype);
                        MimetypeOfFile = Marshal.PtrToStringUni (mimeTypePtr);
                        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem (mimeTypePtr);

                        String fileName = "";

                        If (! String.IsNullOrEmpty (mimetypeOfFile))
                        {
                            Switch (mimetypeOfFile.ToLower ())
                            {
                                Case "application / pdf":
                                    FileName = "Voucher_" + oGarantia.ServiceName + "_" + oGarantia.nroFactura + ".pdf";
                                    Break;
                                Case "image / x-png":
                                    FileName = "Voucher_" + oGarantia.ServiceName + "_" + oGarantia.nroFactura + ".png";
                                    Break;
                                Case "image / pjpeg":
                                    FileName = "Voucher_" + oGarantia.ServiceName + "_" + oGarantia.nroFactura + ".jpg";
                                    Break;
                            }
                        }
                        Var entry = zip.CreateEntry (fileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);

                        Using (MemoryStream fileStream = stream)
                        Using (var entryStream = entry.Open ())
                        {
                            FileStream.CopyTo (entryStream);
                        }
                    }
                    Catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Return null;
                    }
                }
            }
            Return File (ms.ToArray (), "application / zip", "VouchersGuarantees.zip");
        }
```

And to call it from javascript, I use the following line:

```
 Window.location.href = '@ Url.Action ("Download",' Warranties ')';
```

Comment: The idea is to create a method in the controller that brings me certain selected codes in a table with checkbox in the view and with which I will look for the info in the database records, each code, has an attachment, saved in sql, Like varbinary. Then for each one, the idea is to create a file in a zip and be able to download it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an example code that zip files and work, you may adapt your code to it.

First, you will need to install the DotNetZip library.

```
 public FileResult Download()
        {
            // using DotNetZip library
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                // your files (or you can just pull the byte arrays and filenames from your database)
                var file1 = Server.MapPath("~/archivosDescargar/ejemplo 1.pdf");
                var file2 = Server.MapPath("~/archivosDescargar/ejemplo 2.pdf");
                var file3 = Server.MapPath("~/archivosDescargar/1080.png");

                var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file1);
                var byteArray1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file1);
                var fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(file2);
                var byteArray2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file2);
                var fileName3 = Path.GetFileName(file3);
                var byteArray3 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file3);

                // This adds each file to the zip
                zip.AddEntry(fileName1, byteArray1);
                zip.AddEntry(fileName2, byteArray2);
                zip.AddEntry(fileName3, byteArray3);

                using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zip.Save(output);
                    return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip", "sample9.zip");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe Gavilàn. i will try with these library and then will comment you!

Comment: What bad luck I have, I got the same result, I do not understand what's going on, anyway, I'll keep looking.

Comment: Did you try a simple example with pdf's in a directory as I showed you in my code?

Comment: Do not adapt your example to what I had, the problem is that the files I save in the bse of data as binary, I do not understand because when generating the zip, the files added, they are as damaged.

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the files from the database and then sending them to the user (without zipping them)?

Comment: Only one, but if I need to download several, that's the problem. I do not understand what's wrong. I need to download them.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found the error, and it was that I was creating bad zip entries. I was doing it in the following way with the memory stream:

```
zip.AddEntry(fileName, stream);
```

When it should be as follows, with byte []:

```
zip.AddEntry(fileName, oGarantia.comprobante);
```

Your example Felipe Gavilán helped me a lot, many thanks for all the support.